# Recursively traversing a tree in C# from top down by row

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

Interesting problem posed by a friend recently: Imagine you've got a List< NodeType > of all nodes in a tree. How would you go about traversing down the tree from the root node, by row such that you find the first node with a specific value. So say that each node has 3 attributes: its name/location, the identity of its parent, and who "owns" the node. The problem is you want to find the highest node in the tree that you "own" no matter what branch its on. I understand the basic logic in so much as to find the first set of children you look for all nodes with a parent set as the first node. But how would you go about recursively search through a List<> of nodes to find the highest node you own?

Comment: Code please.  At least define the structures you're using...

Comment: No code, its just a logic puzzle we randomly discussed. But it'd be a List of a set of objects. The objects, for example could have a Guid for themselves, a Guid reference to their parent, and any arbitrary value like "apple". In that case, you'd want to find the "highest" element with a value of "apple". Make sense?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You’re looking for **breadth-first search**. It is normally implemented using a queue:

```
public Node FindFirstByBreadthFirst(this Node node, Predicate<Node> match)
{
    var queue = new Queue<Node>();
    queue.Enqueue(tree.RootNode);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        // Take the next node from the front of the queue
        var node = queue.Dequeue();

        // Process the node 'node'
        if (match(node))
            return node;

        // Add the node’s children to the back of the queue
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
            queue.Enqueue(child);
    }

    // None of the nodes matched the specified predicate.
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, yep. Wow, my old algorithms professor would probably end me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Algorithm:

```
Put the root node in a queue.

Repeat
    Take item from queue;
    Matching?  return Item
    Add all children to the queue
Until Queue is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Haha, wow, this is completely wrong, I just realized (as in it is *not* doing what you asked for). Never mind -- looks like you already got a correct answer, anyway :)

---

I think I understand your problem. Let me know if I'm getting something wrong.

You have a `NodeType` class that looks something like this:

```
class NodeType
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public NodeType Parent { get; }
    public int OwnderId { get; }
}
```

First order of business would be to write a function that takes a `NodeType` parameter and, given some enumerable collection of `NodeType` objects, returns all of its descendents in a recursive fashion:

```
IEnumerable<NodeType> GetNodeChildren(NodeType node, IEnumerable<NodeType> nodes)
{
    var children = nodes.Where(n => n.Parent == node);

    if (children.Any())
    {
        foreach (NodeType child in children)
        {
            yield return child;

            var grandchildren = GetNodeChildren(child);
            foreach (NodeType grandchild in grandchildren)
            {
                yield return grandchild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next up: write a function that takes a `NodeType` object and finds the highest descendent with a specified `OwnerId`. This is really a pretty simple operation, so I won't even define a proper function; I'll just use a lambda:

```
Func<NodeType, int, NodeType> findHighestDescendent = (node, id) => {
    return GetNodeChildren(node).FirstOrDefault(child => child.OwnerId == id);
};
```

Now for any given Id value, it is quite trivial to find the highest matching `NodeType`:

```
int id = 10; // just for example

NodeType highestOwnedNode = nodes
    .Select(n => findHighestDescendent(n, id))
    .FirstOrDefault(n => (n != null));
```

Comment: Just as a note... I think you need to change the recursion call to this: `var grandchildren = GetNodeChildren(child, nodes);`

Answer (score -8):

```
public static Control FindChildControlByDepth(this Control Page, string ControlID, int depth)
        {
            if (depth > 10)
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot search beyond a depth of 10", "depth"); 
            foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
            {
                if (c.ID == ControlID)
                    return c;
                if (depth > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Control c1 in c.Controls)
                    {
                        if (c1.ID == ControlID)
                            return c1;
                        if (depth > 1)
                        {
                            foreach (Control c2 in c1.Controls)
                            {
                                if (c2.ID == ControlID)
                                    return c2;
                                if (depth > 2)
                                {
                                    foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                                    {
                                        if (c3.ID == ControlID)
                                            return c3;
                                        if (depth > 3)
                                        {
                                            foreach (Control c4 in c3.Controls)
                                            {
                                                if (c4.ID == ControlID)
                                                    return c4;
                                                if (depth > 4)
                                                {
                                                    foreach (Control c5 in c4.Controls)
                                                    {
                                                        if (c5.ID == ControlID)
                                                            return c5;
                                                        if (depth > 5)
                                                        {
                                                            foreach (Control c6 in c5.Controls)
                                                            {
                                                                if (c6.ID == ControlID)
                                                                    return c6;
                                                                if (depth > 6)
                                                                {
                                                                    foreach (Control c7 in c6.Controls)
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (c7.ID == ControlID)
                                                                            return c7;
                                                                        if (depth > 8)
                                                                        {
                                                                            foreach (Control c8 in c7.Controls)
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (c8.ID == ControlID)
                                                                                    return c8;
                                                                                if (depth > 9)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    foreach (Control c9 in c8.Controls)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        if (c9.ID == ControlID)
                                                                                            return c9;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this solves the original question posed?

Comment: What the heck is this ?

Comment: After being an Stackoverflow user for 5 years, this is the first answer that made me laugh hard and loud. You made my day buddy, and you are one of a kind!

Comment: I'm voting this up because OMG LOL