# Get all Child of Node

Tags: c#

I have a `Node` class below:

```
public class Node {
        public int begin {get;set;}
        public int end {get;set;}
    }
```

Then I create a list with parent and child like this:

```
List<Node> list = new List<Node>();
list.Add(new Node(){begin = 1, end =2});
list.Add(new Node(){begin = 1, end =3});
list.Add(new Node(){begin = 2, end =4});
list.Add(new Node(){begin = 2, end =5});
list.Add(new Node(){begin = 5, end =6});
list.Add(new Node(){begin = 5, end =7});
```

And this is a tree data of list above:

```
        1
    2      3
  4   5
     6 7
```

How can I find all parent of a Node ?
For example, if my `Node` is `2`. The result is: `4,5,6,7`

I tried this code but the result only `4 , 5` when my `Node` is `2`

```
    public static List<int> FindChild(List<Node> list,int id) {
      int value = id;
        List<int> res = new List<int>();

      var child = list.Where(b => b.begin == id).ToList();
      foreach (var item in child) {
          res.Add(item.end);
          FindChild(list,item.end);
      }

      return res;
}
```

Comment: OK, so you don't have a list of *nodes*, you have a list of *edges*. You might want to rename your class to reflect that! Either way, the problem is that you're ignoring the return value of `FindChild` -- you probably want `res.AddRange(FindChild(list, item.end));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively traversing a tree in C# from top down by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518508/recursively-traversing-a-tree-in-c-sharp-from-top-down-by-row)

Comment: Add Parent to your Node class and add the parent when you initialize each node.

Comment: @Orace That other question isn't related -- it's built on nodes which have a parent, whereas this question is built on edges. OP has also almost solved the problem themselves, and your proposed duplicate doesn't help them over the final step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close!

You're correctly finding all edges which have `2` as their parent, and you're correctly recursively traversing all of the children of `2` to find *their* children. The only problem is that you're throwing away this information!

```
public static List<int> FindChild(List<Node> list,int id) {
    int value = id;
    List<int> res = new List<int>();

    var child = list.Where(b => b.begin == id).ToList();
    foreach (var item in child) {
        res.Add(item.end);
        FindChild(list,item.end); // <-- You threw away the return value!
    }

    return res;
}
```

The easiest solution is just to add the return values of `FindChild` to `res`:

```
res.AddRange(FindChild(list,item.end));
```

This [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hy1NwR).

---

You can make this slightly more efficient, and avoid creating lots of new lists and copying their contents around:

```
public static List<int> FindChild(List<Node> input, int id)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    FindChild(input, id, result);
    return result;
}

public static void FindChild(List<Node> input, int id, List<int> result) {
    int value = id;

    var child = input.Where(b => b.begin == id).ToList();
    foreach (var item in child) {
        result.Add(item.end);
        FindChild(input, item.end, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by canton7 in the comments, you are working with edges rather than nodes.

That aside, you aren't currently adding each item in the recursive `FindChild` call to `res`.

Rather than working with lists, it would be more efficient / flexible to use `IEnumerable`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindDescendants(IEnumerable<Edge> edges, int id)
{
    var children = edges.Where(b => b.begin == id);
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
       yield return child.end;
       foreach (var descendant in FindDescendants(edges, child.end))
       {
           yield return descendant.end;
       }
    }
}
```

And if you need a list, you can use LINQ:

```
List<int> descendants = FindDescendants(list, 2).ToList();
```